Initramfs wants to start ATA-over-Ethernet before mounting local (!) root partition
I'm on 22.04 and just did a dist-upgrade to upgrade some helt-back packages, which went through fine. However, my boot now seems to depend on acquiring a DHCP-lease on my ethernet interface.
(Side note: I also have a wifi-interface which aquires a lease just fine, but that's not the point. My boot should never ever block if I don't have network, unless my root filesystem was on a network mount, which it is not).
Here's an extract of my dmesg with comments:
[...]
[    1.767795] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0033, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    1.768998] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
((COMMENT: onscreen I see the following here, but it doesn't show up in dmesg:
Begin: Loading essential drivers... done
Begin: Running /scripts/init/premount... done
Begin: Mounting root filesystem... Begin: running /scripts/local-top... Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
... lots of messages from DHCP failing to get a lease on my ethernet interface until I plug-in a cable...))
[   27.667412] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   30.830852] aoe: AoE v85 initialised.
[   30.897545] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p4): mounted filesystem 0a928e5f-d8c1-4b2a-9d12-b6d814efcf42 ro with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[   31.021829] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[   31.133440] systemd[1]: systemd 249.11-0ubuntu3.11 running in system mode (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
[   31.134679] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   31.137303] systemd[1]: Hostname set to <Laubhaufen>.
[   31.181109] block nvme0n1: the capability attribute has been deprecated.
[   31.248674] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service:11: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
[   31.267985] systemd[1]: Queued start job for default target Graphical Interface.
[...]

Looking at the screen-output, it seems that the initramfs does indeed think that my root partition might be on the network because it doesn't say "done" after "Begin: Mounting root filesystem...". What's going on?
EDIT: my /proc/cmdline contains BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic root=UUID=0a928e5f-d8c1-4b2a-9d12-b6d814efcf42 ro apparmor=0

Researching a bit, it seems that my initramfs-tools has an "aoe"-hook skript, probably because I am actively using ATA-over-Ethernet, just not for my root partition.
Further there's a script /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/aoe which calls a bash-function configure_networking and that one seems to be the culprit. I don't fully understand that function, but I think it's supposed to be used when the root is on an NFS-partition and, since I didn't configure any NFS-related things for my initramfs, it frantically tries to get all network interfaces up before attempting to mount the root-fs. I suppose a bug-report is in order...
EDIT: For future reference, here's the bug-report.
